# Jquery .parent() to get an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

HTML

```
<p href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001ad" class="principal">Fijas</p>
        <div class="menu_body" id="fijo">
        <a href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001ad">Normal (7001AD)</a>
        <a href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001md">Aislada (7001MD)</a>
        <a href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001ad80">A+ (7001AD80)</a>
        <a href="products.php?ref=fijo&tipo=7001md80">A+++ (7001MD80)</a>
        </div>
```

JQ

```
 if(cookie = null)
    {
    $("div.menu_body a").click(function(){
        $.cookie("current",(this).parent().attr("id"));
    });
    }
```

I can't get the ID of the element that I'm pointing to. I don't know if the mistake is with the parent()parent() part or anything else.

Im doing a tab system and I want to check if a tab is opened now, if there is no any cookie, if this tab is opened, and somebody clicks a link in that tab, then store the ID of the .menu_body DIV wich contains that link.

Comment: should that be `cookie == null`? :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say you forgot a char

```
$.cookie("current",(this).parent().attr("id"));
```

should look like this

```
$.cookie("current",$(this).parent().attr("id"));
```

you need to create a jquery object from the "this" object

Answer (score 1):

`(this).parent().attr("id")` is incorrect, because `this` is a DOM element. Try replacing it with:

```
jQuery(this).parent().attr("id")
```

(you can replace `jQuery` with a `$` shortcut)

At the end your code could look similar to this:

```
if(cookie = null){
    $("div.menu_body a").click(function(){
        $.cookie("current", $(this).parent().attr("id"));
    });
}
```